# Google Chart print version bug in Edge?

Tags: html, css, google-visualization, microsoft-edge

I am trying to create a printed version of my HTML page with one google chart in it and the result is not acceptable. I have uploaded an image of the result.

```
  var options = {
    title: 'Muscle Activation',
    colors: ['#e0440e'],
    hAxis: {

    },
    chartArea:{
      bottom: 80,
    },
    width: '100%',
    height: 320,
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom',
    },
  };
```

This is my option code for the google chart that I have and the x-axis labels floated up into the graph in the printed version in Microsoft Edge only. I tested with Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and IE and they do not have this problem. What did I do wrong? I only messes with the width attribute of the div that I use to contain this graph. [image]

Comment: I have no luck with your link but I just found out that the bars are over-extended. They should be starting from the  value 10 .

Comment: I just solved this. All I need to do is add the vAxis: {minValue: 0} so that the graph starts at 0.